# Datatables generating character in single cell

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am using data tables in jQuery AJAX, but the issue is that the data returned is populating an alphabet in a single cell and filling up a row  with letters instead of whole word in a cell. I need like this

```
----------------------------------------
title   |     description  |    location
----------------------------------------
abc               def             ghi
```

while it generates like

```
----------------------------------------
title   |     description  |    location
----------------------------------------
a                 b                 c
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "countr.php",
  data: {
    'countryid': $id
  },
  dataType:'json',
  success: function (data) {                            
    $.each(data.option2, function(key,value) {
      $('#example').DataTable().row.add(value.title).draw();
```

country.php page

```
// some query running and returning data...

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($summaryofresult)) 
{
  $data->option2[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: change `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($summaryofresult)) ` to `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($summaryofresult))`

Comment: it didn't work .

Comment: Try `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($summaryofresult)) 
{
  $data->option2[] = ['title'=>$row['title']];
}
echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: same result  ..... another thing befor each loop i am refreshing datatables like    $('#example').DataTable().clear().draw();
      $('#example').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();